# Why selecting a date\time range into Kibana the query is performed with wrong dates? URL parameters are wrong

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am working on a project involving ElasticSearch and visualizing data on Kibana and I am finding the following problem with date range selection.

As you can see in the following picture I selected I time range that starts from **April 8 2021 at 00:00:00.000** and end at **April 10 2021 00:00:00.000** . Then I clicked the **Refresh** button in order to perform the query.

The problem is that, as you can see in the highligher URL section the passed date range into the query is wrong !!! Infact this is the timerange section of my query into my URL parameters:

```
time:(from:'2021-04-07T22:00:00.000Z',to:'2021-04-10T10:00:00.000Z')
```

As you can see it is pretty differnt from what I selected into the start and end date form fields.

Changing the values into the start and end date form fields automatically changes also the values into the URL parameters but they still wrong.

What could be the problem? Why selecting dates and time into these form fields the parameters value are wrong? What could be the cause of this issue? How can I try to fix it?

I suspect something related to the server timezone (the server where Elastic\Kibana) are installed or something related to some Kibana configuration but I really have no idea

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The kibana [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html) specify:

> The timezone that Kibana uses. The default value of Browser uses the timezone detected by the browser.

So (I'm assuming) your browser default timezone is UTC + 2, meaning when you select `00:00` it's converted to `22:00` UTC timezone, The `Z` in `2021-04-07T22:00:00.000Z` is in indicator here.